# Auditing changes made by an admin on behalf of another user

Tags: security, user, user-management, setup-audit-log

I am wondering whether we have an option/ functionality in Salesforce to store the details of the user who logs as a different user.

Use Case

I am a System Admin (User X) to a Salesforce instance where I can log in to the system as any of the existing Users if this option has enabled in the org. But if something happened in the org when the User X login as User Y, the changes are logged on behalf of User Y. How we can verify/ confirm that these changes happened because of the User X?

Is there any cross-reference between the current logged in user (User Y -> Logged in as User X) with the original user (User X)

Can we check this in the login history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Setup Audit Trail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/admin_monitorsetup.htm) will contain the information you're looking for and you're able to download the last 180 days of changes.

> The history shows the 20 most recent setup changes made to your org.
>   It lists the date of the change, who made it, and what the change was.
>   **If a delegate, like an admin or customer support representative, makes
>   a setup change on behalf of an end user, the Delegate User column
>   shows the delegate’s username. For example, if a user grants login
>   access to an admin and the admin makes a setup change, the admin’s
>   username is listed.**

Setup --> View Setup Audit Trail --> Download setup audit trail for last six months (Excel .csv file)

It'll look like the below where "delegate user" refers to the admin/user logging in as someone else.

[image]

*Also important to note that after 180 days, setup entity records are deleted.*